# Could Arkansas be considered an "Arch Kansas"?

Tags: semantics, names

The prefix arch- means "super" or "stronger than normal" as in the word archenemy. I looked up the etymology of the word Kansas. It said that it is an ethnonym meaning "people of the south wind". Arkansas is located to the south of Kansas. Because Arkansas is to the south of Kansas, could it be called "the arch-Kansas" because it is south of the state with a Native American meaning of south?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. If you look up the etymology of *Arkansas* you can see it has nothing to do with the *arch-* prefix, which anyway is reduced to *arc-*, never *ark-*.

Comment: In fact, you can call anything with any word, as long as it doesn't violate any law in your local area. And forget about that "south wind" nonsense, use [veritable](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=Arkansas) etymological sources.

Comment: I was half kidding. Look at https://wiktionary.org/wiki/Arkansas . This is also a serious question. This is not a commonly available question.

Comment: You're saying (correct me if I'm wrong) 'the prefix' _para-_ say is essentially two different prefixes with different etymologies; shouldn't/couldn't 'arch/ark' be considered similarly (ie 'arch/ark[2]' be a separate prefix, meaning .... // The snag is, according to my reading, 'arch/ark', whether it is a prefix or not,  appeared in _Arkansas_ **before** it entered the English language. Hence not a question about English.

Comment: You are write. I think that this could be *because* it is a semantic experiment. I knew that it appeared in English first with the prefix. In other words, I agree that it didn't show up in English.

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting question is this: Why do residents of Kansas pronounce "Arkansas River" as "Ar-KANSAS River"?

Comment: I have often wondered if Alabama is really à la Bama, and Wisconsin is really "Wiz Consin" in a Swedish accent. Why the votes-down?